# If I disable Location Services, will Find My iPhone continue to work?

Tags: ios, find-my-iphone, geolocation

If I disable Location Services, will Find My iPhone continue to work? I turned off Location Services, but iOS 8.3 is allowing me to leave Find My iPad turned on. The message underneath says though:

`Locating your iPad on a map is disabled. Turn on Location Services to enable it.`

Comment: without knowing for certain - you could always check from iCloud on the web

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Find My iPhone will not continue to work if Location Services is disabled. However, if you enable lost mode, it will automatically enable Location Services.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201357

> In iOS 7, if you turn off Location Services and use Find My iPhone
>   Lost Mode, Location Services will be re-enabled on the device as long
>   as the device is in Lost Mode. Once Lost Mode is disabled, Location
>   Services will return to its previous state.

Comment: I tested on my iPhone with my iPad. Lost mode doesn't seem to work unless I include a phone number or an iMessage. It did briefly turn on Location Services to tell me where the device was located. So, it seems to works as the support article mentions.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Settings > Privacy > Location Services, you can toggle Location Services being on and off. If you turn LS off, everything that uses your GPS location won't be able to fully function. It ranges from small things, like Snapchat's filter options not being available to you, to large things, like Maps not being able to use GPS location. Which is why Find My iPhone will *not* function if you turn LS off completely.

However, you can manage which applications use your location and which do not. Since I am often on the go, and don't want apps like Twitter or Facebook to post my location, I have it set to "Never" for whether or not I allow those apps to access LS. But for apps like Maps and Find My iPhone, I have it set to allow them to access LS and use my location. If you don't do that, you won't be able to use Maps, Find My iPhone, or any app that utilizes the LS function.

Comment: Seems there might be some questionable "facts" in your post after reading nelson2tm's post and the Apple support article.